# Haskell type checking in code

Tags: haskell

Could you please show me how can I check if type of `func` is `Tree` or not, in code not in command page?

```
data Tree = Leaf Float | Gate [Char] Tree Tree deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
func a = Leaf a
```

Comment: The type of `func` is not a `Tree`, it is `Float -> Tree`...

Comment: Furthermore it is not clear to me what you mean by "*in code*". Are you talking about *reflection*?

Comment: thanks but how do i check it? i want to write something like if (func == Tree) 0 else 1 @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @naber2 Reading your question literally, it seems you want to check if e.g. `func 3.7` is really a `Tree`. In that case, there is no need to check: given that `func :: Float -> Tree`, as Willem Van Onsen points out, there is no way `func 3.7` could be anything other than a `Tree`. I suspect that is not what you have in mind, though. You will likely get better suggestions if you explain what the purpose of your test is.

Comment: Is your actual question "How do I tell if it's a recursive tree as opposed to being a leaf?"

Comment: You can run `ghci nameOfYourFile.hs` and then type `:t func` in ghci

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are a few answers, which zigzag in their answers to "is this possible".

1. You could ask `ghci`

   ```
   ghci> :t func
   func :: Float -> Tree
   ```

   which tells you the type.
2. But you said in your comment that you are wanting to write

   ```
   if func == Tree then 0 else 1
   ```

   which is not possible.  In particular, you can't write any function like

   ```
   isTree :: a -> Bool
   isTree x = if x :: Tree then True else False
   ```

   because it would violate *parametericity*, which is a neat property that all polymorphic functions in Haskell have, which is explored in the paper [Theorems for Free](http://ecee.colorado.edu/ecen5533/fall11/reading/free.pdf).
3. But you *can* write such a function with some simple generic mechanisms that have popped up; essentially, if you want to know the type of something at runtime, it needs to have a `Typeable` constraint (from the module [`Data.Typeable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html)).  Almost every type is `Typeable` -- we just use the constraint to indicate the violation of parametericity and to indicate to the compiler that it needs to pass runtime type information.

   ```
   import Data.Typeable
   import Data.Maybe (isJust)

   data Tree = Leaf Float | ...
       deriving (Typeable) -- we need Trees to be typeable for this to work

   isTree :: (Typeable a) => a -> Bool
   isTree x = isJust (cast x :: Maybe Tree)
   ```
4. But from my experience, you probably don't actually need to ask this question.  In Haskell this question is a lot less necessary than in other languages.  But I can't be sure unless I know what you are trying to accomplish by asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to determine what the type of a binding is in Haskell: take something like `f a1 a2 a3 ... an = someExpression` and turn it into `f = \a1 -> \a2 -> \a3 -> ... \an -> someExpression`. Then find the type of the expression on the right hand side.

To find the type of an expression, simply add a `SomeType ->` for each lambda, where `SomeType` is whatever the appropriate type of the bound variable is. Then use the known types in the remaining (lambda-less) expression to find its actual type.

For your example: `func a = Leaf a` turns into `func = \a -> Leaf a`. Now to find the type of `\a -> Leaf a`, we add a `SomeType ->` for the lambda, where `SomeType` is `Float` in this case. (because `Leaf :: Float -> Tree`, so if `Leaf` is applied to `a`, then `a :: Float`) This gives us `Float -> ???`

Now we find the type of the lambda-less expression `Leaf (a :: Float)`, which is `Tree` because `Leaf :: Float -> Tree`. Now we can add substitute `Tree` for `???` to get `Float -> Tree`, the actual type of `func`.

As you can see, we did that all by just looking at the source code. This means that no matter what, `func` will always have that type, so there is no need to check whether or not it does. In fact, the compiler will throw out all information about the type of `func` when it compiles your code, and your code will still work properly because of type-checking. (The caveat to this (`Typeable`) is pointed out in the other answer)

**TL;DR**: Haskell is statically typed, so `func` *always* has the type `Float -> Tree`, so asking how to check whether that is true doesn't make sense.